# Local Volatility Derivation

Tags: local-volatility, volatility-surface

In Jim Gatheral's book (The Volatility Surface), in the first chapter, it says below while deriving Dupire Equation for Local Volatility. I do not understand how the drift term got removed. Can someone please help.

[image]